# get json in play-framwork

Tags: java, playframework-2.4

I want to get a json string with my play-framework application() from a angularJS application.

This is what I actually send:

```
{"in":[
       {"id":4,"ip":"192.168.0.20","pinSysNo":4,"pinSysName":"pg6","folderName":"gpio4_pg6","alias":"d","direction":"digital_in"},
       {"id":3,"ip":"192.168.0.20","pinSysNo":3,"pinSysName":"pb18","folderName":"gpio3_pb18","alias":"c","direction":"digital_out"}
      ],
 "out":[
       {"id":1,"ip":"192.168.0.20","pinSysNo":1,"pinSysName":"pg3","folderName":"gpio1_pg3","alias":"a","direction":"digital_in"},
       {"id":2,"ip":"192.168.0.20","pinSysNo":2,"pinSysName":"pb16","folderName":"gpio2_pb16","alias":"b","direction":"digital_in"}
            ]
}:""
```

I always get the status code 500(internal server error).
May some in my routes are not correct?
routes:

```
POST        /networkInsertJson          controllers.NetworkController.InsertJson()
```

May do I have a problem with the last 3 chars from the json string?

This is my Controller:

```
public static Result InsertJson(){
    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
    try{
        o = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json.asText());
    }catch (Exception e){

    }

    JSONArray ins = (JSONArray) o.get("in");
    JSONArray outs = (JSONArray) o.get("out");

    //I return the json back for testing
    result.put("in", ins.toJSONString());
    return ok(result);
}
```

Could you help me to find the mistake?

Comment: That is not json, it is json with some kind of suffix attached to it, you should fix the source to send proper json

Comment: Now I have Json. I changed the content type in the angular controller to "application/json". But the status code 500 is still there.

Comment: I think @Ferrybig was talking about the trailing `:""` in the JSON payload. Play will error trying to parse that. Do you have a more specific error from the application logs or from the 500 response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own mistake in these line :

```
result.put("in", ins.toJSONString());
```

I tried to insert an array as the content of an json element.